# There is a message when retrieving data from the API (data not found), besides showing the data in one place it, it works

Tags: android, api, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

There is a message when retrieving data from the API (data not found), besides showing the data in one place it, it works

So the time I run it does not come out anything, and it turns out after I debug directly past this code `_detailTvShow.value = listResult`

And then bring up the message in the log :

message : Expected an int but was 537523f9c3a3681ef4000177 at path $.created_by[0].credit_id

localizedMessage : Expected an int but was 537523f9c3a3681ef4000177 at path $.created_by[0].credit_id

DetailsTvShowResponse

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class DetailsTvShowResponse (

    @Json(name = "id")
    val idDetailsTvShow: Int?,

    @Json(name = "backdrop_path")
    val backdropDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "created_by")
    val createdByDetailsTvShow: List<CreatedBy>?,

    @Json(name = "first_air_date")
    val firstAirDateDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "genres")
    val genresDetailsTvShow: List<GenresMovieOrTvShow>?,

    @Json(name = "homepage")
    val homepageDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "in_production")
    val inProductionDetailsTvShow: Boolean?,

//    @Json(name = "languages")
//    val languagesDetailsTvShow: ArrayList<String>?,

    @Json(name = "name")
    val nameDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "number_of_episodes")
    val numberOfEpisodesDetailsTvShow: Int?,

    @Json(name = "number_of_seasons")
    val numberOfSeasonsDetailsTvShow: Int?,

    @Json(name = "origin_country")
    val originCountryDetailsTvShow: Int?,

//    @Json(name = "original_language")
//    val originalLanguageDetailsTvShow: ArrayList<String>?,

    @Json(name = "original_name")
    val originalNameDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "overview")
    val descriptionDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "poster_path")
    val posterDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "production_companies")
    val productionCompaniesDetailsTvShow: List<ProductionCompanies>?,

    @Json(name = "seasons")
    val seasonsDetailsTvShow: List<Seasons>?,

    @Json(name = "status")
    val statusDetailsTvShow: String?,

    @Json(name = "vote_average")
    val ratingDetailsTvShow: Double?,

    @Json(name = "vote_count")
    val ratingCountDetailsTvShow: Int?
)
```

ApiService

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface ApiService {
    @GET("movie/now_playing?api_key=$TMDB_API_KEY&language=en-US&page=1")
    fun getNowPlayingMoviesAsync():
            Deferred<NowPlayingMoviesResponse>

    @GET("movie/{movie_id}?api_key=$TMDB_API_KEY&language=en-US")
    fun getDetailMoviesAsync(@Path("movie_id") movieId: Int?):
            Deferred<DetailsMovieResponse>

    @GET("tv/popular?api_key=$TMDB_API_KEY&language=en-US&page=1")
    fun getPopularTvShowsAsync():
            Deferred<PopularTvShowsResponse>

    @GET("tv/{tv_id}?api_key=$TMDB_API_KEY&language=en-US")
    fun getDetailTvShowAsync(@Path("tv_id") tvId: Int?):
            Deferred<DetailsTvShowResponse>

}

object Api {
    val retrofitService: ApiService by lazy {
        retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

DetailTvShowViewModel

```
class DetailTvShowViewModel(idTvShow: Int, application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var viewModelJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(viewModelJob + Dispatchers.Main)

    private val _detailTvShow = MutableLiveData<DetailsTvShowResponse>()
    val detailTvShow: LiveData<DetailsTvShowResponse>
        get() = _detailTvShow

    private val _navigateToHomepage = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val navigateToHomepage: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _navigateToHomepage

    init {
        getDetailTvShow(idTvShow)
    }

    private fun getDetailTvShow(idTvShow: Int) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            val getDetailTvShowDeffered = Api.retrofitService.getDetailTvShowAsync(tvId = idTvShow)
            try {
                val listResult = getDetailTvShowDeffered.await()
                if (listResult.nameDetailsTvShow != null) {
                    _detailTvShow.value = listResult
                } else {
                    Log.i("DetailTvShowViewModel", "Completed : ${getDetailTvShowDeffered.isCompleted}" )
                }
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("DetailTvShowViewModel", "message : ${t.message.toString()}")
                Log.i("DetailTvShowViewModel", "localizedMessage : ${t.localizedMessage}")
                Log.i("DetailTvShowViewModel", "printStackTrace : ${t.printStackTrace()}")
                _detailTvShow.value = null
            }
        }
    }

//    val displayGenreList: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(detailTvShow) { response ->
//        val genreName = response.genresDetailsTvShow?.map { it.nameGenreMovie }
//        "Genre : ${genreName?.joinToString(separator = ", ")}"
//    }
//
//    val displayRating: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(detailTvShow) {
//        "${it.ratingDetailsTvShow} Out of ${it.ratingCountDetailsTvShow} review"
//    }
//
//    val displayNumberOfSeason: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(detailTvShow) {
//        it.numberOfSeasonsDetailsTvShow.toString()
//    }
//    val displayNumberOfEpisodes: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(detailTvShow) {
//        it.numberOfEpisodesDetailsTvShow.toString()
//    }

    fun onHomepageClicked() {
        _navigateToHomepage.value = true
    }

    fun onHomepageClickedComplete() {
        _navigateToHomepage.value = false
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Model property List is not able to map to join value created_by

Therefore you need to create custom Jason adapter to parse this property and then add that adapter to moshi builder e.g
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().add(new MyCustomAdapterFactory()).build();

Refer example link for using adapter :
https://proandroiddev.com/getting-started-using-moshi-for-json-parsing-with-kotlin-5a460bf3935a